# How do we prove that the fundamental group is a group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

My understanding of the fundamental group is that it's the set of all loops starting and ending at a point $x_0$ in a space $X$, along with the operation of composition. For it to be a group, composition of loops must be associative, loops must have inverses, and the identity must exist. In our case, the identity is the constant map at $x_0$, and composition is defined as follows:

$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} f_1(2x) & \text{if } x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]\\ f_2(2x-1) & \text{if } x \in [\frac{1}{2},1]\\  \end{array} \right.$

I'm struggling to understand how we can prove this because the proofs I've seen (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Topology/The_fundamental_group for example) will construct homotopies between things they wish to show are equal. Why is this allowed, instead of following the definition of loop composition? Let's say you have a loop $g$, and then $g^{-1}$ must just be $g$ run backwards. If you compose them, you go along $g$, and then you go back at the same speed. How can we use a homotopy to claim that this is the same as staying stationary at $x_0$?

Comment: The link you give does explain that the elements of the group are Homotopy Classes of loops (starting with classes of paths) - but not in a hugely explicit way. There is some work to be done to show that the composition of classes is well defined (doesn't depend on the representatives chosen). Then everything works and it is legitimate to treat homotopic paths as "the same" because they are in the same class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fundamental group is not a group of loops, but of *equivalence classes* of loops. In particular, two paths are equivalent if they are homotopic. So showing associativity, for example, requires showing that $$[f]([g]  [h]) = ([f]  [g]) [h],$$ where $[f]$ is the equivalence class containing $f$, that is, all loops homotopic to $f$.

The operation of the fundamental group is $[f][g] = [f \star g]$, where $\star$ is the composition of paths. Of course, one must prove that this operation is well-defined. Once you have shown that it is, to show associativity is to show that $$[f \star (g \star h)] =[(f \star g) \star h]$$ which is to show that $f \star (g \star h)$ is homotopic to $(f \star g) \star h$.

Answer (score 4):

> My understanding of the fundamental group is that it's the set of all loops starting and ending at a point $x_0$ in a space $X$, along with the operation of composition.

Nope! As you're probably aware, what you're describing is *not* a group. The elements of the fundamental group are the *homotopy classes* of loops - i.e. loops modulo the equivalence relation of being homotopic.